# AVPlayer Go To Live?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am using an `AVPlayer` object to play a live stream of an MP3, just using an HTTP link.

As with normal live video playing in iOS, there is a button that you can press to skip to live.

Is it possible to do this with `AVPlayer`?

E.g I am listening live, `pause`, then after however long `play` again. It continues from where I left it. But what if I want to skip to live?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need and made this extension to AVPlayer:

```
extension AVPlayer {
    func seekToLive() {
        if let items = currentItem?.seekableTimeRanges, !items.isEmpty {
            let range = items[items.count - 1]
            let timeRange = range.timeRangeValue
            let startSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeRange.start)
            let durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(timeRange.duration)

            seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(startSeconds + durationSeconds, 1))
        }
    }
}
```